# Group by Date and find the minimum and maximum values of temperature in JSON array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

I have a data from a weather forecast api like this https://jsfiddle.net/ammarabdulaziz/dvzyo37m/1/#&togetherjs=sl9DNSolHU

It is a weather forecast for 5 days every 3 hours. I want to group data with the date and find the minimum and maximum temperature of Each day.

Expecting output format:

```
[
{
"dt_txt" : "2021/7/2",
"min_temp": 282.06,
"max_temp": 300.05
},
{
"dt_txt" : "2021/8/2",
"min_temp": 282.06,
"max_temp": 300.05
},
{
"dt_txt" : "2021/9/2",
"min_temp": 282.06,
"max_temp": 300.05
},
{
"dt_txt" : "2021/10/2",
"min_temp": 282.06,
"max_temp": 300.05
},
{
"dt_txt" : "2021/11/2",
"min_temp": 282.06,
"max_temp": 300.05
},
]
```

I tried this,

```
var result = [];
            newArray.reduce(function (res, value) {
                if (!res[value.dt_txt]) {
                    res[value.dt_txt] = { dt_txt: value.dt_txt, value };
                    result.push(res[value.dt_txt])
                }
                return res;
            }, {});
```

But it is only grouping the dates. I am not able to find min max values and add to each day object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot find min, max because there is no operation to check/assign it value, `.reduce` is little complicated, I will use normal loop

```
var tmpResult = {};
var result = [];

// create unique object and use date as key
newArray.forEach(function(item) {
  var min = item.main.temp_min;
  var max = item.main.temp_max;
  if (!tmpResult[item.dt_txt]) {
    tmpResult[item.dt_txt] = {
      "min_temp": min,
      "max_temp": max
    }
  } else {
    var prevMin = tmpResult[item.dt_txt].min_temp;
    var prevMax = tmpResult[item.dt_txt].max_temp;
    tmpResult[item.dt_txt] = {
      min_temp: min < prevMin ? min : prevMin,
      max_temp: max > prevMax ? max : prevMax
    }
  }
})
console.log(tmpResult)
// { 2021-02-07: {min_temp: 292.25, max_temp: 300.25} }

// convert to array object
for (var date in tmpResult) {
  result.push({
    "dt_txt" : date,
    "min_temp": tmpResult[date].min_temp,
    "max_temp": tmpResult[date].max_temp
  })
}

console.log(result)
// [ {dt_txt :'2021-02-07', min_temp: 292.25, max_temp: 300.25}, {...} ]
```